# canvas to base64 on image src

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, base64

I want to convert the rawImg to base64 and pass it on image.src. I will be needing the base64 dataURL to put effects on my canvas.
Pls see my code below:

```
function onLoad() {
    canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      if (image.width != canvas.width)
        canvas.width = image.width;
      if (image.height != canvas.height)
        canvas.height = image.height;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      filterCanvas(imageFilter);
    }

    var rawImg = "flower.jpg";
    imageURL = <-- (convert rawImg to base64.. I dont know what to write here)
    image.src = imageURL;


 }
```

Comment: Use [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Comment: @Kaiido, Or rather in the callback of `filterCanvas` if it is asynchronous..

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. I'm new to canvas. Where and how should I use .toDataURL() to convert the rawImg to base64?

Answer (score 6):

> Use [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), *returns a data `URI` containing a representation of the image in the format specified by the type parameter(The default type is `image/png`)*

```js
function onLoad() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    if (image.width != canvas.width)
      canvas.width = image.width;
    if (image.height != canvas.height)
      canvas.height = image.height;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    filterCanvas(imageFilter);
    var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    YOUR_IMAGE.src = imageURL; //Select `YOUR_IMAGE` using getElementById/querySelector/...
  }
  image.src = "flower.jpg";
}
```

Comment: @Kaiido, True..Updated.. Quiet surprised by your observation skills ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I really dont know how I will use DOM api for this. I also dont need to use filereader for this.

Comment: @R.C., You are saying or asking ?

Comment: Hi Rayon, sorry for the confusion. I was asking how to use DOM api for the code.

Comment: Hi, I still can't make the image.src to be base34

Answer (score 0):

With HTML snippets as:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<span>Resultant data URL: </span><span id="result"></span>
```

And, updating your javascript code as below:

```
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    if (image.width != canvas.width)
      canvas.width = image.width;
    if (image.height != canvas.height)
      canvas.height = image.height;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   // filterCanvas(imageFilter);
    var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    alert(imageURL);
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = imageURL;
  }
  image.src = "flower.jpg";
```

You will get the resultant base64 string within the `#result` span element. Please try this.